# Some Emojis not appearing on browser and some applications in Endeavour OS

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, special-characters, emoji

I just shifted to arch from ubuntu budgie. and I am getting some issues loading/displaying emojis on some websites and applications. I have provided some screenshots of the issue. The Os I am using is Endeavour OS with KDE Plasma Desktop and my browser is Brave (stable).

1. A post on Facebook which probably had emojis

[image: A post on Facebook which probably had emojis]

2. VS Code Terminal there should have been arrows which do show up on konsole (kde terminal) shown below

[image: There should have been arrows which show do show up on konsole kde terminal shown below]

3. The konsole which shows the arrows

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a font related issue. I don't know about the first one, it should bring its own font, but you can try changing font.

About the second one, [Powerlevel](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#fonts) works best with [Nerd Fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts), and they specifically recommend [Meslo](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#meslo-nerd-font-patched-for-powerlevel10k) (I use the Bitstream one). Alternately, try running `p10k config` in VS Code terminal and me may take you to a right config.